# How do I prove this question involving primes?

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

Find, with proof, all primes $p$ for which $p^7-2018$ is the square of a prime.
I'm pretty sure that p=3 is the only number that satisfies this, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$ p^7 = 2018 +q^2$$ for some prime $q$.

Say $q\ne 3$, then $q^2 \equiv_3 1$, so we have $$ p^7 = 2018 +q^2\equiv_3 2+1 \equiv_3 0 $$ 
so $p=3$. If $q= 3$ then $$p^7 = 2027$$
which is impossible.

Comment: You have 2 possibilites. If $q=3$ and if $q\ne 3$. I made complete analysis.

Comment: ok i see it now, but does it prove that p=3 is the only answer?

Comment: If $p$ is prime and $p \ne 3$ then $p^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ by FLT.  So $p^7 \equiv 1 \mod 3$.  If $q$ is prime the $q^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ if $q \ne 3$  $2018\equiv 2 \mod 3$ so $p^7 - q^2\equiv 0 \not \equiv 2018 \mod 3$ so $p^7 = 2018 + q^2$ is impossible if p and q are not 3.  If q is then then $p^7 = 2027$ which impossible

Comment: "but does it prove that p=3 is the only answer"  It proves that if $p \ne 3$ then there is no solution.  So....  yes.

Answer (score 0):

if $p\equiv 0 \mod 3$ then $$p^7-2018\equiv 1 \mod 3$$ then is the solution $p=3$
if $$p\equiv 1 \mod 3$$ then $$p^7-2018 \equiv 0 \mod 3$$
if $$p\equiv 2 \mod 3$$ then $$2^7-2018 \equiv 0\mod 3$$ so the only case is $$p=3$$

Comment: How does $q^2$ fit into this.  why cant $q^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ or $q^2 \equiv 0 \mod 3$.

Comment: ok if $$q^2\equiv 0 \mod 3$$ then must $$q\equiv 0\mod 3$$

Comment: if $$p\equiv 0\mod 3$$ then must $$p=3$$ since $p$ is a prime number

Comment: any other questions?